# Can Intents/Intent Filters be used for more mundane tasks?

Tags: android

I have a pretty good understanding of what Intents and Intent Filters can do, but I was wondering if it would be possible to use them to perform something a bit more mundane, like maybe just monitoring a change in a variable value.

This is unfortunately a bit of a noob question, and it is probably just my inexperience with Java and Android so far. The task I'm trying to accomplish is really just to have a method that is added to the lifecycle that can detect a simple change and react without having to add a method call to the end of every user triggered action. I've thought of adding a game-like thread with an infinite loop that calls a method repeated on a slight delay... but it seems like that would be overkill.

Thanks a lot,
Jeremiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe java events would help you here. This sounds like events, listeners and handlers would be good for this problem.

If you dont know what events are: They will wait for a certain event to occur and you can attack listeners to those events that will trigger when an event has happened. This creates "a mini-thread" basically. So it will go off and execute and return back without interrupting code. This is from my understanding over the past couple days.

I recently made a post about this to get some better examples, because i am still learning them myself, check it out. I will be posting stuff there as soon as i can figure it out and maybe someone else will too eventually.
[java events,handlers and listeners question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818851/java-events-handlers-and-listeners-question)

Comment: I just updated my example for the link i gave you. Check it out and see if that helps you out.